# Most efficient way to update database

Tags: performance, postgresql, sql-update, auto-update

I have a table that is auto-updating from time to time (say daily). All updated fields are of type `TEXT`, and might have lots of data. What I definitely know is that the data will not change a lot. Usually up to 30 characters added or deleted. 
So what would be more efficient? To merge somehow the changes or delete the old data and retrieve the new one?
And, if the merge way is the way to do it, how should I do that? Is there any keyword or something in order to make this easier and more efficient?

P.S I am completely new to databases in general, it's the very first time I ever create and use a database, so sorry if it is a silly question

Comment: If at all possible, split your fields up into their logical parts rather than storing them as a big `text` blob, so you can update only the chunks that actually need to get updated. Try to normalize the data and structure it.

Comment: @CraigRinger yeah, I will scale it later, but I need to get it working until friday, so for now I'll do it like I presented my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the [MVCC](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/mvcc-intro.html) model, PostgreSQL *always* writes a new row for *any* set of changes applied in a single `UPDATE`. Doesn't matter, how much you change. There is no "merge way".

It's similar to (but not the same as) deleting the row and inserting a new one.

Since your columns are obviously big, they are going to be [TOASTed](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/storage-toast.html), meaning they are compressed and stored out-of-line in a separate table. In an `UPDATE`, these columns can be preserved as-is if they remain unchanged, so it's considerably cheaper to `UPDATE` than to `DELETE` and `INSERT`. Quoting [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/storage-toast.html)

> During an `UPDATE` operation, values of unchanged fields are normally
>   preserved as-is; so an `UPDATE` of a row with out-of-line values incurs
>   no `TOAST` costs if none of the out-of-line values change.

If your rows have *lots* of columns and only some get updated a lot, it might pay to have two separate tables with a 1:1 relationship. But that's an extreme case.